# ldap ObjectSID string to hex

Tags: php, ldap, hex, data-conversion, ldap-query

I can't figure out how to search in an ldap directory by objectsid string:

```
$string =  'S-0-1-23-4567890123-4567890123-456789012-3456'
$ds = ldap_connect('xxxx', xxx);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
$r = ldap_bind($ds, $bind_rdn, $bind_password);
$filter = "(objectSid=$string)";
$sr = ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter); 
$users = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
```

Then i read somewhere you should pass it as hex value:
/00/00/....

```
$s = preg_replace('/../','\\\\$0',bin2hex($string));
```

But still no result. If i pass objectSid=* ass filter, i get all results, so i know the query is working :).

Thx!

Comment: I found a [piece of code](https://github.com/Alaneor/AD-X/blob/develop/ADX/Core/Converter.php#L319) somewhere which converts the byte-array into the SID-string. If you can reverse the process, you are good to go (and please share the code, too).:)
Also, if you have the option, use ObjectGUIDs instead of SIDs. [Here's why](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961625.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have searched for both `objectGUID` and `objectSID` using the escaped hex codes of the binary values.

If you can take the values an put it in a 16 byte array and convert it to hex encoded characters then you can do something like this...

```
(objectguid=\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00)    

(objectsid=\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00)
```

where \00 represent the actual hex values of the bytes in the byte array.  This works very well and it is very fast. You can even test it in an LDAP client so you can see it work first.

As the responder above stated, I would use objectGUID instead as it is immutable unlike objectSID which can change.